# Multiple apps published from a single Google Play Store developer account are unable to be downloaded simultaneously

Tags: react-native, google-play-console

I created two app using React Native app1 and app2. Then I published this apps on Google Play Store by my developer account . I'm using single developer account for both of the apps and both apps are now available in Play Store but problem is that if I install the app1 and then if I want to download the second app then I'm not able to download the app2.
For downloading app2 first I have to delete the app1 then second app is downloaded successfully .Here are the error which I got when I try to download the second app with the presence of first app1: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHcHL.jpg)

And the link which is given in the image [is](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/14122894?hl=en&error=6004&ctx=com.ycic&isid=JCl1pOOBSC6cxA18sAmQGA&visit_id=638424692801223479-2756529275&p=fix_download_install&rd=1).

I want to install both apps, can you help about how to solve this problem?

Although the package names and app names for both applications are different, I want to to be able to install both applications without deleting one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have these apps (or apps with the same package name) installed on your phone from some other source (debugging from for example Android Studio or APK), if so, uninstall it and try again.